# How to wrap like side scroll game?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to create a game with boats on a 2d screen and want to get them to wrap if they were to go off the screen.

```
public static void placeBoat (char [][] boat,int x, int y ){
    for(int row = 0; row < boat.length; row++){
        if(row==x){
            for(int column = 0; column < boat[row].length; column++){
                if(column==y){boat [x][y] = '>';
                boat [x][y-1] = '=';
                boat [x][y-2] = '|';
                boat [x][y-3] = '|';
                boat [x][y-4] = '=';
                boat [x][y-5] = '<';
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

So as an example this is what happens when I get these coordinates and this is what it prints.The coordinate references where the front of the boat is printed and then the rest of the boat is printed to the left of it.

```
1,18,
6,19,
2,6,
5,8,
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~<=||=>~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~<=||=>~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~<=||=>~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~<=||=>~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The problem I am having though is trying to figure out how to do this if one of the coordinates has as y value less then 5 because then the other pieces of the boat would be off the screen and it I get an `outofbounds` exception like if `y` was `4` then it will be 4-5 and I will get an out of bounds exception.

I was going to do an `if(y<5)` and do separate statements for that, but then I would have to do that for when `y` is `4`, `3`, `2`, `1` and `0`.

Comment: What do you want to wrap: the entire boat or its individual characters?

Comment: not the whole boat but individual character so if the cords for one of the boats was 0,1 then in the first line would look something like this >~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~<=||= so only the parts that went out of bounds will wrap

Comment: Then use modulo when after incrementing your coordinate. Have a look: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58063/screen-wraparound

Comment: Hmm I am confused as to what I am moding.Like for this would i do [x][(y-5)%33] = '<';  if y was 4, because that would just give me 0. Unless I am not understanding correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the boat parts to wrap to the left, then you have to calculate the `y` position before placing the parts, and a loop is not a good place for it.

In general your method does not need to loop through the grid at all because you are only placing one boat at a time.

The whole method can be replaced with a calculation of the boat positions based on the `x` and `y` values, and then just modifying the grid directly.

```
public static void placeBoat(char [][] boat, int x, int y){
    // the first part is at y
    boat [x][y] = '>';

    // size is 5 because there 5 more parts to the boat
    int[] nextYs = new int[5];

    for (int j = 0; j < nextYs.length; j++) {
        // next y is at y - 1
        int nextY = y - 1;

        // next y is to the left
        if (nextY >= 0) {
            // set y to - 1
            y = y - 1;
        // next Y is to the right
        } else {
            // next y and y itself should be set to the last column
            nextY = y = boat[x].length - 1;
        }

        nextYs[j] = nextY;
    }

    // print the other parts                
    boat [x][nextYs[0]] = '=';
    boat [x][nextYs[1]] = '|';
    boat [x][nextYs[2]] = '|';
    boat [x][nextYs[3]] = '=';
    boat [x][nextYs[4]] = '<';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest solution would be to use modulo operator.

For simplicity of the solution, I would advise to change the functionality slightly - rather than `y` being the position of the right end of the boat, it now will be the position of the left end of the boat.

If you have an array of length `n = 5` and you are placing 3 characters starting at position `p = 4`, you want the characters to be at position 4, 0, 1:

```
BCxxA
01234
```

So without wrapping the code would be:

```
array[p]     = 'A' // 4 + 0 = 4
array[p + 1] = 'A' // 4 + 1 = 5 - IndexOutOfBoundsException
array[p + 2] = 'A' // 4 + 2 = 6 - IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Notice that the positions 4, 5, 6, modulo 5, give you 4, 0, 1, which is exactly what you need:

```
array[p]           = 'A' // 4 + 0               = 4
array[(p + 1) % n] = 'A' // (4 + 1) % 5 = 5 % 5 = 0
array[(p + 2) % n] = 'A' // (4 + 2) % 5 = 6 % 5 = 1
```

So in your case that would be:

```
public static void placeBoat(char[][] boat, int x, int y) {
    boat[x][y] = '<';
    boat[x][(y + 1) % boat[x].length] = '=';
    boat[x][(y + 2) % boat[x].length] = '|';
    boat[x][(y + 3) % boat[x].length] = '|';
    boat[x][(y + 4) % boat[x].length] = '=';
    boat[x][(y + 5) % boat[x].length] = '>';
}
```